Association constants of α-cyclodextrin with phenols
I have an exercise that asks me to reason the why for the association constants of a α-cyclodextrin with the guest.

The higher the K the higher the stability of the complex, but I don't quite understand why methyls in ortho with -NO2 have K=0 and with -O: and -OH do not.
Is it just a matter of stereochemistry? Can't the guest enter the cavity when the methyls are next to the nitro?
This makes me wonder why it is the nitro that has to go into the cavity and couldn't it go the other way around?

Jonathan Steed & Jerry Atwood addressed this specific case in their text on Supramolecular Chemistry (Ch. 6, Sect. 6.3.3.). The structure of all cyclodextrins can be thought of as a 'tapered cylinder', with a narrower primary face, and a wider secondary face. You are correct in your assumption that the nitro group is included towards the narrower face (and so anything interfering with this tapered inclusion, say methyls) will result in complexation being less favored. As for the why—nitro groups are more hydrophobic than phenol(ate) groups, though I am unsure why this is.

By unsure, I mean I do not have a satisfactory reason for why nitro is weakly-hydrogen bonding. Either way, complementarity is quite an important aspect in molecular recognition. The better the size fit on both ends, the better the complexation. As for why the $\ce{-O^-}$ is leads to 'better' complexation than $\ce{-OH}$, this is because the extra delocalization of the lone pair from the phenolate into the ring enhances dipole-dipole and van der Waals interactions, which leads to a better complexation with the internal cavity of the CD ring.

@Sonder: Your comment(s) make(s) some sense. I think you should put these arguments as an answer to the question, even if you are unsure. You can make them reliable with some references.

Your question is not clear to me for some reason. Are you looking for why different association constants for different phenols or why $\alpha$-CD associate with phenols. Also, the values would differ with the buffer used. Can you verify the buffer used here?

@Sonar thank you very much for your commentary, I found it very enlightening. I would also like to know why the -NO2 would be less polar or more hydrophobic. All in all you helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

@Mateo Mahindaratne
I'm sorry for the confusion. I have a hard time communicating in English. Thank you very much. You only have to “justify” reasonably why some species form the complex better than others.

Eftink and Harrison (Ref. 1) have reported that anionic form of the ligand, p-nitrophenol (p-nitrophenolate) binds to $\alpha$-cyclodextrin ($\alpha$-CD) at least 10-fold more strongly than the neutral ligand. This statement is true when compared to given $\log K$ values of relevant compounds (3.36 vs 2.32), which is approximately 11-fold. Bergeron and coworkers (Ref. 2) have suggested that the preferential binding of anion results from improved London dispersion interactions with this form of the ligand.
According to Ref. 2:

Cycloamylose-Substrate Binding: In principle, sodium p-nitrophenolate can penetrate the cyclohexaamylose cavity effectively in only two different orientations (Figure 5), either oxygen or nitro end first. A third orientation with penetrating ortho and meta positions is unreasonable, simply because very little of the substrate would fit into the cavity. However, $\ce{^1H}$ NMR studies clearly indicated that sodium p-nitrophenolate penetrated the cyclohexaamylose cavity at the wide 2,3-hydroxyl side nitro end first and only to the extent that the meta protons were in close proximity to the cycloamylose 3-$\ce{H}$ protons.

The modified Figure 5 (to show details) is as follows:

Accordingly, either the sodium p-nitrophenolate(s) or p-nitrophenol(s) can only bind in the cavity of $\alpha$-CD nitro-end first, may be because this orientation represents an energetically slightly more favorable disposition (may be the formation of hydrogen bonds with $\ce{O-H}$ groups at narrow-end  $\alpha$-CD with $\ce{N-O}$ of nitro-group). If sterically prohibited such as the situation in 3,5-dimethyl-4-nitrophenol, one can be suggest that the substrate can reorientate itself and penetrate the cavity hydroxy-end first and bind (Ref. 2). However, measured values of dissociation constant, $K_\mathrm{D}$ in Ref. 2 clearly shows that the substrate can only binds nitro-end first:
$$
\begin{array}{l|cc}
\text{Substrate} & K_\mathrm{D} \text{ by } UV \ (\pu{25\pm0.1^\circ C}), \ \pu{M}   & K_\mathrm{D} \text{ by NMR } (\pu{23\pm0.5^\circ C}), \ \pu{M} \\
\hline
\text{4-nitrophenol} & 5.3 \times 10^{-2} & -  \\
\text{4-nitrophenolate} & 4.0\pm 0.8 \times 10^{-4}  & 3.7\pm 0.2 \times 10^{-4}  \\
\text{2,6-dimethyl-4-nitrophenol} & 1.76\pm 0.18 \times 10^{-3} & -  \\
\text{2,6-dimethyl-4-nitrophenolate} &  9.42\pm 1.1 \times 10^{-4}  & 1.96\pm 0.53 \times 10^{-4} \\
\text{3-methyl-4-nitrophenol} & \text{did not bind} & -  \\
\text{3-methyl-4-nitrophenolate} & 4.2\pm 0.4 \times 10^{-2}  & 3.5\pm 0.16 \times 10^{-2}   \\
\text{3,5-dimethyl-4-nitrophenol} & \text{did not bind}  & -  \\
\text{3,5-dimethyl-4-nitrophenolate} & \text{did not bind}  & \text{did not bind}   \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Just to be clear, the dissociation constant $K_\mathrm{D}$ is defined in Ref. 2 as follows:
$$\ce{CS <=>[$K_\mathrm{D}$] C + S}$$
$$K_\mathrm{D} = \frac{[\ce{C}][\ce{S}]}{[\ce{CS}]}$$
where $\ce{C} = \text{$\alpha$-CD}, \ \ce{S} = \text{substrate, and } \ce{CS} = \text{$\alpha$-CD bound substrate}.$
The comparison of $K_\mathrm{D}$ values suggests followings:

In all cases, the neutral phenol binds in the cavity more weakly than its corresponding anion. For instance, sodium 4-nitrophenolate binds about 130 times tighter than the phenol.
Introduction of methyl groups at the 2 and 6 positions of 4-nitrophenolate weakens binding only slightly by a factor of about 2.4.
However, introduction of a single methyl group at the 3 position of 4-nitrophenolate weakens the binding substantially by a factor of about 100.
Introduction of methyl groups at both the 3 and 5 positions completely inhibits binding (steric hindrance for nitro-end first entry, see Figure 5 above).

It is important to note that Ref. 1 report that nitrobenzene binds to $\alpha$-CD  with binding constant similar to that of 4-nitrophenol. This suggests that the nitro group is of primary importance of determining the binding of these ligands to  $\alpha$-CD. The direct formation of a hydrogen bond between the hydroxyl group (phenol-$\ce{OH}$) of 4-nitrophenol and 2,3-hydroxyl groups of wider end $\alpha$-CD does not contribute significantly to binding.
References:

M. R. Eftink and J. C. Harrison, "Calorimetric studies of p-nitrophenol binding to $\alpha$- and $\beta$-cyclodextrin," Bioorganic Chemistry 1981, 10(4), 388-398 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0045-2068(81)90051-1).
Raymond J. Bergeron, Michael Almy Channing, George J. Gibeily, and David M. Pillor, "Disposition requirements for binding in aqueous solution of polar substrates in the cyclohexaamylose cavity," * J. Am. Chem. Soc.* 1977, 99(15), 5146–5151 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00457a040).


As I described in a previous answer, the structure of the cyclodextrins can be thought of as a 'tapered cylinder,' with a narrow face (called the primary face) and a wide face (called the secondary face). [1-3] This allows the cyclodextrin to create hydrophobic micro-domains within the cavity. There are many contributing forces to the favorability of the inclusion: one may consider this to be how willing the guest is to enter the cavity of the host.  (1) complementarity, or the structural similarities between the host cavity and the guest molecule; and (2) intermolecular forces, such as van der Waals, dipole interactions, and hydrogen bonding. What I would like to emphasize is the role of complementarity [4]. Simply put: if the guest cannot fit into the cavity, an inclusion is never going to happen!

Experimentally, we have shown that even when hydroxyl groups are included into the cyclodextrin, it prefers to include with such group outside the cavity [5]. I draw your attention to the figure from their paper, though this describes nicotinic acid (I believe the example is still valid however). I assume it does the same with these molecules. This model tells us that it is the nitro group that is included towards the narrow end, leaving the hydroxyl group quite happy being surrounded by a rich number of alcohol groups exocyclic to the cavity.

We are talking about alpha-cyclodextrin here: benzene already has a similar size to the cavity of the host (0.53nm for alpha-CD; 0.45nm for benzene, approximately [6]). This means that if the methyl groups are oriented ortho- towards the nitro group, the inclusion is sterically disallowed. It's like forcing a shape that won't fit into the box. By contrast, when the methyl groups are ortho- to the hydroxyl group, which is exocyclic anyway, this steric effect does not influence the ability of the nitro group to enter the cavity of the host. In fact, you can almost see this compound tapering from wider to narrower itself. Mathew Mahindarante's answer should provide some graphical representations of this.
The log(K) you provide shows an increased favorability when the hydroxyl group is deprotonated to form the phenolate. Why is this? Recall that it is a combination of complementarity and intermolecular forces that lead to the favorability of the inclusion. In the phenolate, the electron density that is delocalized over the benzene ring has increased, so intermolecular forces have also increased.
Remember that the methyls, even when they are ortho- to the hydroxyl group, still have a steric factor. It is better for the molecule in terms of complementarity for them to not be there. This is why the dimethyl derivative has a lower log(K) than the non-methylated derivative, in both cases when the hydroxyl is protonated and deprotonated, respectively. Perhaps the case is different when we use a larger cyclodextrin, as there is more space in the cavity and reduced steric effects.


Ariga, K., Kunitake, T.; Supramolecular Chemistry — Fundamentals and Applications, Sect. 2.7: Cyclodextrin – A Naturally Occurring Cyclic Host, Springer, 2006, pp. 21
Steed, J. W., Atwood, J. L.; Supramolecular Chemistry, Sect. 6.3: Cyclodextrins, 2nd Ed., Wiley, 2009.
Battle, C. H., Jayawickramarajah, J.; Supramolecular Approaches for Inhibition of Protein–Protein and Protein–DNA Interactions, Wiley, 2012.
Lehn, J. M.; Sumpramolecular Chemistry — Scope and Perspectives. Nobel lecture, December, 1987.
Saha, S., Roy, A., Roy, K. et al. Study to explore the mechanism to form inclusion complexes of β-cyclodextrin with vitamin molecules. Nature Scientific Reports 6, 35764 (2016).
Szczupaj et al. (2024). NMR studies of complex formation between natural cyclodextrins and benzene. Journal of Inclusion Phenomena and Macrocyclic Chemistry, February, 2024.

